# How can I use sed to append lines between two patterns?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, append

I have a file and I'm trying to figure out how to use sed to append the text as follows; the file has lines with state and then lines with cities from that state.

```
state NY  
city Manhattan  
city Brooklyn  
city Bronx  
end state  
state CA  
city Los Angeles  
city San Francisco  
city San Diego  
end state  
state IL  
city Chicago  
city Springfield  
city Rockford  
end state
```

Trying to end up with output were the header info (state) is appended to the end of the city lines so I end up with a file like this:

```
city Manhattan,NY  
city Brooklyn,NY  
city Bronx,NY  
city Los Angeles,CA  
city San Francisco,CA  
city San Diego,CA  
city Chicago,IL  
city Springfield,IL  
city Rockford,IL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/^state/{val=$NF;next} val{print $0","val}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation too now.

```
awk '
/^state/{         ##Check condition if a line starts from string state then do following.
  val=$NF;        ##Creating variable val whose value is last field of current line.
  next}           ##Using next keyword to skip all further statements.
val{              ##Checking condition if variable val is NOT NULL then do following.
  print $0","val  ##Printing current line with command and variable val here.
}'  Input_file    ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: wow thanks for the quick response!!!  Worked perfectly.  New to scripting can you explain what this does?  Thanks

Comment: @A.Harris, sure, added explanation too now, check and let me know on same, in case of any queries.

Comment: DOWN VOTER, please do let let me know reason for down vote here.

Comment: much thanks for the solution and explanation!!  again greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^state/h;/city/!d;G;s/ *\nstate /,/;s/ *$//' file
```

Copy any line that begins `state` to the hold space (HS). Delete any line that does not contain the word city. Append the HS to the pattern space (PS). Remove any spaces at the end of the current line, the appended newline and the literal `state` followed by a space. Remove any additional spaces at the end of the line.